# Clicking on a dynamic link in selenium

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, xpath, selenium

I need to click on link in a table whose id is generated dynamically. I want to click on a link based on a text in some other column in the same row. Tried the following code but unsuccessful

selenium.GetValue("//table[@id=TableID]/tbody/tr[td/a/text()='Testing']")

Also trying with the following code
Selenium.click("xpath=id(TableID)/tbody/tr[td/text()='Testing']//input [@value='Delete']")

Tried the following code but only works by specifying a static row id

```
 Dim NumOfRows As Integer = selenium.GetXpathCount("//table[@id='up']/tbody/tr")
        'Dim index As Integer
        Dim ReturnValue As Integer
        Dim IsFound As Boolean = False
        Console.WriteLine(NumOfRows)

        For i As Integer = 1 To NumOfRows
            Dim strColumnText As String = selenium.GetText("//table[@id='up']/tbody/tr[i]/td[1]")
            'selenium.WaitForCondition(strt, 100000)
            If (strColumnText = pord) Then
                ReturnValue = i
                IsFound = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
```

If I specify exact row it will find the element but not working in a loop. pls help

Comment: For an XPath expression as answer you need to provide an input sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value are in a table you should use

```
selenium.getTable("tableName.0.1");
```

Where 0 is the row and 1 is for the column (0 based index both of them)

getTable will return an string if successful: "OK,value" so you need to strip out the OK, part.

**Update**
Add to user-extensions.js

```
    Selenium.prototype.getTableRows = function(locator) {
  /**
   * Gets the number of rows in a table.
   *
   * @param locator element locator for table
   * @return number of rows in the table, 0 if none
   */

    var table = this.browserbot.findElement(locator);
    return table.rows.length.toString();
};
```

Selenium RC

```
// Table Name in inputParams

    String[] inputParams = { "tblTryggHuvudlantagare", };

                String y = proc.doCommand("getTableRows", inputParams);
                String tmpString = y.replace("OK,", "");

                // Rows minus headings


    int tableRows = Integer.valueOf(tmpString).intValue() - 1;

        for (int i = 1; i < tableRows; i++) {
    // Your logic here to see if you reached the right row and then click button on same row..
                    }
```

Comment: here you are specifying exact row and col but I have to select a row based on value 'testing' and then clicking the delete button on same row in another column. Any idea how to do this..

Comment: I once made a solution where I had to iterate the table to find my value to get the row number. From there I guess you now what column the delete button.. I had to make a JavaScript to get the size of the table as Selenium will throw and exception if you try non existing rows. Will have a look and see if I find my solution and add it to my answer.

Comment: Tried with the option you specified with the following code  
       For i As Integer = 1 To NumOfRows
                Dim strcolumntable As String = selenium.GetTable("ctl00_cphMain_gvOperatorGroup.i.1")

                'selenium.WaitForCondition(strColumnText, 100000)
                If (strcolumntable = pKey) Then
                    ReturnValue = i
                    IsFound = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
Getting same porblem with both codes...Not iterating through loop. If provide a static row value works fine but not iterating. Any help plz

Comment: selenium.GetTable("ctl00_cphMain_gvOperatorGroup.i.1")  should that not be selenium.GetTable("ctl00_cphMain_gvOperatorGroup." + i + ".1")

Comment: Thanks Stefan .Yes tried this too but getting Conversion from string to type double is not valid. Tried the following
            For i As Integer = 2 To NumOfRows
                If (selenium.GetTable("Group." + i + ".1") = pKeyword) Then
                    ReturnValue = i
                    IsFound = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
Any idea why I am getting this

Comment: Thanks stefan It works. just need to convert i to string
selenium.GetTable("ctl00_cphMain_gvOperatorGroup." + i.tostring + ".1")